# adaptive thresholding ---ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, adaptive-threshold

I'm pretty amateur at image processing. I could successfully do normal thresholding but however I'm facing an error in Adaptive Thresholding.
Here is my code:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("vehicle004.jpg")

img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_,th2=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

cv2.imshow("window2",th2)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error Message:

```
line 7, in <module>
    _,th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding), the `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` returns only 1 value that is the **threshold image** and in this case you are trying to receive 2 values from that method, that is why  `ValueError: too many values to unpack` error is raised.

After fixing the issue the code may look like:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("vehicle004.jpg")

img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

th2=cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

cv2.imshow("window2",th2)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```